# Windows online troubleshooting service is disabled

Tags: windows, windows-10, troubleshooting

I get this error when running a blue screen troubleshooter.

> Windows online troubleshooting service is not enabled for this version of Windows

[image: windows online troubleshooting disabled]

How do I enable it?

I'm using Windows 10 20H2

[image: software publishing registry folder]

Comment: Try running DISM / SFC:   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: We will need more information.  Do you have the group policy `Scripted Diagnostics` enabled or disabled?  Provide a screenshot indicating the contents of `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WinTrust\Trust Providers\Software Publishing.` which will allow us to potentially diagnose your problem.  We will need the logs and the output of both `SFC /SCANNOW` and `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` by the way

Comment: >>>>>>>https://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-online-troubleshooting-service-is-disabled

Comment: I don't have Group Policy Editor as I'm running the home edition, not the professional edition.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the registry screenshot.

Comment: I've done the instructions that John, Ramhoud and Moab provided and it still doesn't work. Dism gave me 5 errors. Here's my dism log. https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2097362

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Blue Screen troubleshooter is no longer available starting with Windows 10 version 1809.

Source: [How to Run Blue Screen Error (BSOD) Troubleshooter in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/62704-run-bsod-error-troubleshooter-windows-10-a.html) from Ten Forums